# How can I use AppLocalization in TextFormField (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

How can I use AppLocalization in TextFormField (Flutter)

Comment: go through this article https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization ... it might help you!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

delete const before InputDecoration